# Slowness in Production Environment

Tags: performance

We have .NET application (code written in C Sharp) which parses many XMLs and also perform XML/XSLT Transformation.

This functionality is slower on our production server to compare to development machine.
On Production server this function (parsing and  XML/XSLT Transformation) takes around 6 seconds, while on development machine it takes around 3 seconds.

Developer Machine: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07 GHz, Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1)-64bit, 8 GB RAM, .NET Framework v4.0.30319, SATA drive

Production Server: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 @ 2.40 GHz (2x CPU Quad Core), Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise-64bit, 48 GB RAM, .NET Framework v4.0.30319, SCSI drive

I expect production server to be more faster than development environment? What could be reason for slowness on Production Server?

Please let me know if any further any information required.

Comment: Does developer machine has SSD? What about Server, do you have HDD (not SSD) there? Performance issues of multiple small files are usually the result of poor hard drive.

Comment: Show your code please, otherwise question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

On developer machine SATA drive.
On Production machine SCSI drive. 

We don't have code...Its third party code DLL.

Comment: start PerfMon on both the environments. Look at CPU, RAM, I/O stats and see how they are different in the 2 environments. Maybe on the server there are a bunch of other processes running, other users connected,...
Moreover XML processing is CPU bound and it doesn't matter how many CPUs/cores you have. A 3Ghz CPU could perform better than a 2.4Ghz one.